# What is the technical term for people who either lends or borrow money?

Tags: loanwords, finance

For example, if i am giving people money expecting to be paid back or i borrow money from them promising to pay back without any interest. What would these people be called?

Comment: That's not what [loanword](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loanword) means! I'm slightly wondering if this question is just an excuse for a pun.

Comment: Won’t let me post my answer, so here it is: a **neither**. Think Shakespeare.

Comment: @StuartF -  I don’t think there is a lone word for both those concepts.

Answer (score 1):

**Moneylender and Borrower**

A person that lends money is a moneylender, and the opposite of a moneylender is a borrower.
[wordhippo.com](https://www.wordhippo.com/what-is/the-opposite-of/moneylender.html)